# Does network traffic monitored by android.net.TrafficStats accruate?

Tags: android

I want to get accurate network traffic generated by android app ::

```
long totalTraffic = TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(uid) + TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(uid);
```

the idea is straightforward, linux system assign each android app an UID, with this UID, static method retrieve all received and sent network traffic data for the specified `application(uid)`, including 2G/3G and wifi traffic.

however, the traffic statistics queried from Telecom operator are usually twice or three times bigger than the way above I monitored.

Answer (score 1):

> however, the traffic statistics queried from Telecom operator are
>   usually twice or three times bigger than the way above I monitored.

This is because big data blocks will be buffered on the way from the internet to your device.

Even if you don't receive the whole data on your device. (for example cancel a loading video)

> Totals-methods (getTotalRxBytes(), getTotalTxBytes(), ...) always
>   return correct data.
>   Source: http://agolovatyuk.blogspot.de/2012/04/android-traffic-statistics-inside.html